# How can we push or published multiple message and keep session open

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

How can we push or published multiple message one after another to same Web-socket Session in spring?

```
public Flux<WebSocketSession> openWebSocket() {
Flux<String> input = Flux.just("{\"action\":\"auth\",\"params\":\"SomeKEY AUTH\"}\n",
        "{{\"action\":\"subscribe\", \"params\":\"subcriptionmessage.*\"}");
Flux<String> input1 = Flux.just("{{\"action\":\"subscribe\", \"params\":\"AM.*\"}");
Flux<String> input2 = Flux.just("{\"action\":\"auth\",\"params\":\"SomeKEY AUTH\"}\n");
ReplayProcessor<Object> output = ReplayProcessor.create(100);

try {
    webSocketClient.execute(new URI("wss://***"),
            session -> {
                log.debug("Starting to send messages");
                return session
                        .send(input.doOnNext(s -> log.debug("outbound " + s)).map(session::textMessage))
                        .thenMany(session.receive().map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText))
                        .delayUntil(i -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
                        .doOnNext(s -> log.debug("inbound " + s))
                        .subscribeWith(output).then();
            }).block();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);

}
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my payload and its works it was an issues with payload , had invalid json input string

Actual :  "{**{**"action":"subscribe", "params":"subcriptionmessage.*"}"

Expected :  "{"action":"subscribe", "params":"subcriptionmessage.*"}"